# how do i send Json request to a server- java project (NetBeans)

Tags: java, json, netbeans

i'm trying to send Json request to a server from my java project, the problem is, i found a class that someone wrote, in which he uses Apache, i tried to make path to the apache but it still doesnt import this stuff:

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

here's the class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class JsonHTTPRequest {
    private static String postToURL(String url, String message, DefaultHttpClient httpClient) throws IOException, IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException, RuntimeException {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(message);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        StringBuffer totalOutput = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            totalOutput.append(output);
        }
        return totalOutput.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apatche is third party so you have to include apatche lib take a look at this [page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient403sourcesjar.htm)